# Linking libavformat in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, ffmpeg, libavformat

I'm attempting to build some video-reading code around libavformat. After getting the compiled DLLs and `.lib` files [here](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/), I go to build my code, and the linker can't find any of the libavformat symbols even though I've linked in the provided  `.lib` files.

Inspecting `libavformat.lib` with `dumpbin -headers` reveals that it exports the desired functions with an underscore prefix. For example, while I want to call `avformat_open_input`, the .lib file gives `_avformat_open_input`.

Why is this, and why can't I link the precompiled dlls?

Comment: Is your application x64 platform too? Also please copy the exact error message here.

Comment: I'm just building a 32-bit application. The linker errors are just your traditional

    LibavVideoReader.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl avformat_open_input(struct AVFormatContext * *,char const *,struct AVInputFormat *,struct AVDictionary * *)" (?avformat_open_input@@YAHPAPAUAVFormatContext@@PBDPAUAVInputFormat@@PAPAUAVDictionary@@@Z) referenced in function...

messages

Comment: Are you compiling your code as C or as C++? If the latter, did you make sure the C declarations from those libraries are wrapped in `extern "C"`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to do following all tasks to use `libav` with `MSVC++`. First goto [Zeranoe](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/)

1. Download `Shared` Version, Copy all `.dll` files from `bin` folder and paste them in the output directory where `exe` will be generated.
2. Download `Developer` Version, Copy all `.lib` files from `lib` folder and paste them with your main c++ file is located (e.g. `Folder-1\Folder-2` Where `Folder-1` has the `.sln` file so you have to put `.lib` files in `Folder-2`)
3. From `Developer` Version you downloaded in Step 2 copy all directories from `include` folder and paste them in Folder-2 (See details about Folder-2 in step 2)
4. Download [inttypes.h](http://code.google.com/p/msinttypes/source/browse/trunk/inttypes.h) and [stdint.h](http://code.google.com/p/msinttypes/source/browse/trunk/stdint.h), save it on this location `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\` folder.
5. To include header files use following syntax

You have to use this `extern` because `libav` is a `C` library.

```
extern "C" {
    #include "libavcodec/avcodec.h"
    #include "libavdevice/avdevice.h"
    #include "libavfilter/avfilter.h"
    #include "libavformat/avformat.h"
    #include "libavutil/avutil.h"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fetch the 32-bit libraries and you should be fine :) Your application platform has to match the libraries used (and vica versa).

Comment: I am using the 32-bit ones. What would lead you to believe otherwise?

Comment: The function name decoration. Are you sure you picked the good libs? _ExportedNameStartingWithUnderscore is x64 decoration.

Comment: It was a C/C++ issue. Wrapping the headers in `extern "C" { }` fixed everything.

Answer (score 0):

What about compiling it as a .lib static library?