# How to resolve LINK errors due to addition of .lib files to a C++ project in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, c

I've created a new c++ project with Visual Studio Pro 2012.

I tried to add C language `1ib` files,but I'm getting some **LINK** errors like:

`Error 2 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol  _av_malloc@4 referenced in function  _video_encode_example@4 D:\C-Sharp\C++ Compiling\ConsoleApplication7\ConsoleApplication7\example.obj ConsoleApplication7`

On my part I went to **"Properties"** on my **"Project Name"** in the `Solution Explorer`, then  to `Linker > Input` and then at the top,in  **Additional Dependencies** I did **edit** and added all the `.lib` files:

```
avcodec.lib
avdevice.lib
avfilter.lib
avformat.lib
avutil.lib
```

Do I need to add more missing .lib files ? I looked again and these are the only .lib files I have.

I didn't change anything else in the Linker.In the VC++ I changed the Include Directories to: `D:\C-Sharp\C++ Compiling\ConsoleApplication4\ConsoleApplication1\include`

In the `include` directory there are some directories in each directory along with some header files.

The reference directories and library directories changed both to the same directory: 'D:\c++dev\ffmpeg-20130418-git-ee94362-win64-dev\lib'.In this directory there are `Lib` files,`DEF` files and some `A` files.

How can I resolve these errors ?

** I search in google i tried to change the SubSystem to Console but it didn't help.
** I have main function already:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "targetver.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    return 0;
}
```

I have 8 LINK errors and error number 9 is:

Error   10  error LNK1120: 8 unresolved externals   D:\C-Sharp\C++ Compiling\ConsoleApplication7\Debug\ConsoleApplication7.exe  1   1   ConsoleApplication7

What else can i do to resolve this problems ?

** EDIT **

Changed the project target to x64 now i have only two link erros:

Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol avcodec_open referenced in function video_encode_example  D:\C-Sharp\C++ Compiling\ConsoleApplication7\ConsoleApplication7\example.obj    ConsoleApplication7

And

Error   3   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals   D:\C-Sharp\C++ Compiling\ConsoleApplication7\x64\Debug\ConsoleApplication7.exe  1   1   ConsoleApplication7

Tried to make double click on them but nothing. I'm not sure what to do now.

Answer (score 2):

I just spotted in your question that you're using ffmpeg libraries.

If you want to link these into a C++ project, you have to make sure that you wrap the `#include` statements in an `extern "C"` block, like this:

```
extern "C"
{
    #include "avformat.h"   // etc. etc.
}
```

This will fix the link errors by making sure that the exported function names are not mangled on import.

Comment: I tried now almost everything and now i put around all the #include i did extern "C" {... But im getting now more then 100 errors. Before all changes i had 9 errors of this link thing. I also copied all lib files to where the exe should be and did everything in this link answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11301864/linking-libavformat-in-visual-studio-2010 wich is marked as answer. Still not working. Now im getting more then 100 idfferent errors before i had only 9 link errors the 100 errors came after i added this extern "C"

Comment: You should only put the `extern "C"` around the `#include`'s for the ffmpeg headers - is that what you did?

Comment: I changed the project targer to be x64 when i have downloaded the dll's and bin files it was for 64bit. So now after compiling all 9 errors of the link gone. Now i have two other errors of LINK2019. I just updated my question with this two erros.

Comment: I removed all the extern "C" if i added this i get over 100 errors. Removed it had 9 link2019 errors after changed to x64 target i have now one link2019 error.

Answer (score 0):

Try including the paths of your *.lib files on:

**Linker** -> **General** -> **Additional Library Directories**

Comment: If the path wasn't there, he'd get an error saying the files can't be found.