# C2059 syntax error 'string' ?

Tags: c++, c

```
extern "C" 
{
#endif
#include <stdint.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include "attributes.h"
}
#endif
```

I added `extern "C" { }`
Then i got the `C2059 string` error
So i tried to use `#endif`, now i have another 4 errors.

```
Error   1   error C2059: syntax error : 'string'    d:\c-sharp\c++ 
compiling\consoleapplication7\consoleapplication7\libavutil\rational.h 31 1
ConsoleApplication7
```

How can i fix this string error ?

Comment: Why do you do this in the first place?

Comment: `#ifdef X ... #endif` is normally how it goes, not `#endif` twice. Unless you haven't posted all your code?

Comment: The `extern "C" {` declaration and closing `}` would normally be enclosed by `#ifdef __cplusplus`, `#endif`.  If you don't do this, you'd have to ensure your header wasn't included from a C source file

Comment: Please post the _original_ code, as complete as possible (also please see http://sscce.org/ for help). Then please post the complete and unedited error messages, while pointing out what line in the source they are about.

Comment: Joachim the original post the problem of my code is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16155783/how-to-resolve-link-errors-due-to-addition-of-lib-files-to-a-c-project-in-vis i have 9 erorrs of this link. I tried to google and tried any solution copied all bin files and dll files to the debug and to the solution directories nothing helped. So i tried this extern "C" but it didn't help either. Can't figure out why this errors happen.

Comment: I can upload my complete project it's very small to my skydrive maybe someone can take a look on it ? I'm trying to use C language function part of ffmpeg in my c++ project. So i tried to use all dll's i have downloaded and bin files and i set all directories in the project properties also in the linker properties. But nothing helped so far.

Comment: This is the ffmpeg code i tried to use in my c++ project: http://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/encoding_8c-source.html the function from line 195 only this function.

Comment: The goal for now is just to put the c ffmpeg function in my c++ project and to compile it see that it will compile without errors see that the function is doing and working as it should be. That's what i need to do now.

Comment: Here is a link to my project: https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=EB1C71C44C3976D5!194&authkey=!ANAmiEavuqaqKDk maybe someone can see it and find out why i'm getting those link errors.

Answer (score 27):

At a guess, are you including this code from a C source file?

`extern "C" {` guards are  only required (or understood) by C++.  You can omit them from a C file, should include them in a C++ file and should guard them with a  `__cplusplus` ifdef in a header file.

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
#include <stdint.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include "attributes.h"
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Comment: You wouldn't normally put the headers within the `extern "C" { }` section.