# Accessing DLL function using ctypes

Tags: python, c, dll

I have been trying to convert a C-code to DLL and load it from Python but I have never succeeded. I am using Windows10
(64bit). The original C code is quite simple:

```
//Filename: my_functions.c
# include <stdio.h>
int square(int i){
    return i*i
}
```

I summarize the two approaches I have tried so far.

### Method1

First, I built the 64-bit dll by `cl.exe` on Command Prompt:

```
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat" -arch=x64
```

```
cl.exe /D_USRDL /D_WINDLL my_functions.c /MT /link /DLL /OUT:my_functions.dll /MACHINE:X64
```

As a result, I got a file `my_functions.dll`. Subsequently, I tried to load it by the following Python code (Python 3.8, Spyder):

```
# Filename: calling_c_functions.py
from ctypes import *
my_functions = CDLL("./my_functions.dll")
print(type(my_functions))
print(my_functions.square(10))
print("Done")
```

However, I got the error:

`AttributeError: function 'square' not found`.

Why does this happen? According to the document in Microsoft: [Exporting from a DLL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/exporting-from-a-dll?view=msvc-160), a DLL file contains an exports table including the name of every function that the DLL exports to other executables. These functions need to be accessed either by `ordinal number` or by `name` (different from the original name 'square').

This brought me to Method 2 below.

### Method2

Based on [Python: accessing DLL function using ctypes -- access by function *name* fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088085/python-accessing-dll-function-using-ctypes-access-by-function-name-fails), I first created a DLL file by myself using the keyword `__declspec(dllexport)`:

```
//Filename: my_functionsDLL2.dll
#include <stdio.h>
extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) int square(int i);
}
__declspec(dllexport) int square(int i)
{
   return i * i; 
}
```

The next step is to find a real function name in the `my_functionsDLL2.dll` by `link.exe`. I did the following on the Command Prompt.

```
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\link.exe"
```

```
link /dump /exports my_functionsDLL2.dll
```

I should be able to see a list of function names but ended up getting the following output:

```
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 14.29.30037.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file myfunctionsDLL2.dll
myfunctionsDLL2.dll : warning LNK4048: Invalid format file; ignored

  Summary
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track but got a bit confused along the way - taking a code file and giving it a `.dll` extension isn't enough to turn it into a DLL, you do still need to compile it. Your linker is telling you that it doesn't know how to parse your file:

> myfunctionsDLL2.dll : warning LNK4048: Invalid format file; ignored

because it only knows how to parse real executables.

---

You should rename your second code file (the one you named `my_functionsDLL2.dll`) back to `my_functions.c` - and compile it the same way you did the first time. But this time, because you added `__declspec(dllexport)` to your function definition, your compiler (`cl.exe`) will know that these functions are meant to be exported from the DLL and will export them, making them available through ctypes.

Answer (score 2):

I needed to make 2 modifications to my current approach.

The first modification is the one pointed out by @Daniel Kleinstein. But only with that, I stil got an error: `C2059: syntax error: 'string'`. This error is due to `extern "C" {` guards that are only understood by C++ (reference: [C2059 syntax error 'string' ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16169522/c2059-syntax-error-string) ). For a C source file, I needed to add `__cplusplus` ifdef.

I summarize the overall procedures that led me to the correct result (there may be some redundancies though).

1. I want to call the following C file from Python.

```
//Filename: my_functions.c
#include <stdio.h>

int square(int i){
   return i * i;
}
```

2. Create a C file using `__declspec(dllexport)` and `__cplusplus ifdef`.

```
//Filename: my_functions2.c
#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
    __declspec(dllexport) int square(int i);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

__declspec(dllexport) int square(int i)
{
    return i * i;
}
```

3. Create a 64-bit dll file `my_functions2.dll` by running the following commands on Command Prompt. You need to locate the `cl.exe` carefully on your computer.

```
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat" -arch=x64
```

```
cl.exe /D_USRDL /D_WINDLL my_functions2.c /MT /link /DLL /OUT:my_functions2.dll /MACHINE:X64
```

4. Call the `my_functions2.dll` from Python using `ctypes`. In this example, I test the function `square` and obtain a correct result.

```
#Filename: call_my_functions2.py
import ctypes as ctypes 
my_functions = ctypes.CDLL("./my_functions2.dll")

print(type(my_functions))
print(my_functions.square(10))

print("Done")
```

I get the following output:

```
<class 'ctypes.CDLL'>
100
Done
```