# error LNK1120: unresolved externals

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ffmpeg

I am trying to build the following code. But it gives the error as "error LNK1120: 5 unresolved externals". I'm using C++ in Visual Studio 2013. Libraries are included properly. Error comes at avformat_open_input method. I'm using muxing in ffmpeg in my code. Please help.

```
const char *url = "H:/Sanduni_projects/ad_2.mp4";

AVFormatContext *s = NULL;
int ret = avformat_open_input(&s, url, NULL, NULL);
if (ret < 0)
    abort();

AVDictionary *options = NULL;

av_dict_set(&options, "video_size", "640x480", 0);
av_dict_set(&options, "pixel_format", "rgb24", 0);

if (avformat_open_input(&s, url, NULL, &options) < 0){
    abort();
}

av_dict_free(&options);

AVDictionaryEntry *e;

if (e = av_dict_get(options, "", NULL, AV_DICT_IGNORE_SUFFIX)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Option %s not recognized by the demuxer.\n", e->key);
    abort();
}

avformat_close_input(&s);
```

Comment: You should add library into your project at *Project Properties -> Linker -> Input*.

Comment: Already added the libraries properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

problem fixed. I added this to the code

```
extern "C" {
    #endif
    #include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
    #include <libavformat/avformat.h>
    #include <libswscale/swscale.h>
    #ifdef __cplusplus 
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing some linking with libraries in your project.
[Linking libavformat in Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11301864/linking-libavformat-in-visual-studio-2010?answertab=votes#tab-top) will help you more.